# change status of windows services in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, winapi, service

How can i change current state of a windows service from a C/C++ program ??

for example say, Mysql is running as a service and its current status is 'Started'... how can I check the status and how can i change its status from a c/c++ program? like if I want to change its status from 'Started' to 'Stopped' - how can i do it in c/c++?

Comment: It is more a WinAPI question than a C++ one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`QueryServiceStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684941%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) can be used to determine the status of a service.

Look at the other [Service functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685942%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to change the status. There is even a complete [Starting a Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686315%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) example (and the matching [Stopping a Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686335%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) code).

Answer (score 2):

A small code snippet that should you get you started:

```
/* Open service control manager. */
SC_HANDLE scm_handle = OpenSCManager(0,
                                     0,
                                     SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
/* Ensure (0 != scm_handle) */

/* Open service. */
SC_HANDLE service_handle = OpenService(scm_handle,
                                       "mysql-service-name",
                                       SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
/* Ensure (0 != service_handle) */

/* Try to stop the service if it is running. */
SERVICE_STATUS status; /* This may need populated differently for mysql. */
status.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
if (ControlService(service_handle, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, &status))
{
    Sleep(1000);

    while (QueryServiceStatus(service_handle, &status))
    {
        if(status.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        {
            Sleep(1000);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (status.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOPPED)
    {
        /* Success: service stopped. */
    }
    else
    {
        /* Failure: service not stopped. */
    }
}
else
{
    /* Failed to issue stop request. */
}

CloseServiceHandle(service_handle);
CloseServiceHandle(scm_handle);
```